# Git: How to skip to the end of a rebase and keep all changes so far?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-interactive-rebase

I'm in the middle of an interactive rebase and I've already amended several commits

I have several remaining commits that I've marked to edit, but I've decided that I don't want to edit them anymore

How can I end the rebase (early, if you would) but keep the changes I've made so far?

`git rebase --abort` will end the rebase and erase all of the changes I've made, and `git rebase --continue` is too tedious to type for every remaining commit I have to edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run:

```
git rebase --edit-todo
```

To edit the instructions of the remaining commits. You'll then be able to change all the commits you marked as `edit` into `pick`. Then just run:

```
git rebase --continue
```

And it will carry on without stopping (unless conflict) until the end.